# android decoding video frame not displayed properly - interlacing problem?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ffmpeg

I am beginner in android. I am working on porting ffmpeg to android and i am able to display the picture, which looks really odd. I am providiing the links to pictures please advice me what really went wrong in my case.

In the native code I call sws_scale function to convert image from native format to rgb 565 and I use this rgb565 frame to be displayed using canvas and bitmap in java code.

I am guessing this is interlacing problem, but not sure. Need suggestions . Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling ffmpeg? I definitely agree that its an interlacing issue. Can you just pass `deinterlace` to it?

Comment: I am using the ffplay provided with ffmpeg code. I call avcodec_decode_video2 and then using sws_scale to convert it into RGB565 format, then display it as bitmap. Now I don't understand what went wrong with the way I am doing.